# Number of solutions to equation with at least one odd number

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the equation:
$ 2x_1 + 5x_2 + 2x_3 + 5x_4 = 14 $. I need to find the number of solutions it has in $ \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\} $ such that there is at least one odd number. I need to find two ways to do so, are the following ways correct?

Finding the complement: find the number of solutions where none of the numbers are odd and therefore it becomes the equation $ 2x_1 + 10x_2 + 2x_3 + 10x_4 = 14 $. Find he coefficient of $ x^4 $ in $ f(x) = (1 + x^2 + x^4 \ldots x^14 )^2(x^{10}) $

Choose one number to be odd: therefore the generating function is $ f(x) = (x^5)(1 + x^5 + x^10)(1 + x^2 + x^4 + \ldots + x^{14})^2 $. Find the coefficient kf $x^{14} $.

Comment: "*choose one number to be odd*"  Careful here... do you mean choose *exactly one* to be odd, or exactly two, or exactly three, etc...  If you just choose one to be odd and don't mean for it to be "exactly one" or similar then are you making sure to account for the possibility of overcounting where the one is odd and the might also be?

Comment: For the first approach, why did you increase the coefficients of $x_2$ and $x_4$ to twice their original, i.e. $10$... but not increase the coefficients of $x_1,x_3$ to twice their originals?  Why just $x^{10}$ in the g.f. and not $1+x^{10}$?  Why is this portion not squared?

Comment: @JMoravitz because $ x_1, x_2 $ are already even. I multiplied $ x_2,x_4 $ by two so that they divide by $ 5 $ and $ 2 $.

Comment: So when you write that (at least) one of the numbers must be odd, you really mean one of the terms of the sum must be odd, not that (at least) one of the $x_i$ must be odd?

Comment: "*because $x_1,x_3$ are already even*"  Wrong.  It may be true that $2x_1$ is even but that is not the same thing as $x_1$ being even.  One of the example solutions here would be $(1,2,1,0)$ corresponding to $2\cdot 1 + 5\cdot 2 + 2\cdot 1 + 5\cdot 0 = 14$.  In this example $x_1$ is odd, it is equal to $1$.  While it may be true that in the expansion we have $2\cdot 1$ appearing at the front of $2\cdot 1 + 5\cdot 2 + \dots$ and we have $2\cdot 1$ is even, that is *not* what we are talking about when we talk about $x_1$ being even or odd.  We cared about the $1$ in $(1,2,1,0)$